# How to switch to boot device's root file system from initramfs

Tags: linux-kernel, initramfs, root-filesystem

I've been working on an operating system using the Linux kernel. I've successfully compiled the kernel and can boot into my initramfs through it.

The issue arises when I try to switch from initramfs to the actual boot device the operating system has been booted from. For this, I've even set up a system to programatically determine the boot device so users can boot the OS from a bootable USB or even a CD with the OS burnt onto it.

Everything works well until I try to use `switch_root`: it fails and afterwards, my OS becomes unable to run some stuff saying `pty` cannot be found. Please help.

Comment: Please provide the failure message and the exact pty failure message.  Also, do you have an fstab file written?

Comment: Fortunately, I've come to a solution, I'm about to add my answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I've come to a solution.

I switched from creating my own `initramfs` with BusyBox and instead have an automatic one created using `dracut`. `dracut` handles the mounting of the root file system and even the switch to it.